# How to create a time variable that is always updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, cron, momentjs

I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't seem to find anything that helps, I hope the title make sense, I'm new to javascript and node. In short, I am creating bot for an internal messaging system (like slack). My bot is a reminder bot, so a user can type in the keyword and say "remind me of 'x' in 10 minutes" or "remind me to do 'y' on April 30th at 9:00am" etc.

In my head it made sense to just a have global time variable that is constantly updated like:

```
if(currentDateTime >= reminderArray[0].notificationTime){
    bot.sendMessage(reminderArray[0].message);
    reminderArray.shift();
}
```

push all the reminders on a global queue where they are sorted by reminder time and then execute the bot to send a message when the global time equals the time of the first item in the queue.

I am having a really hard time figuring out how to have a live updated global time variable. I have looked into cron jobs but I'm not sure how to have multiple cron jobs running at the same time.

I have no idea if I'm thinking about it too much or not, it's been like 3 days of banging my head on my keyboard so I might just be in a hole and the answer is probably really simple. Anyways if you can shed any light, offer any advice, or show any examples/tool that I can use I would be so thankful.

Wait, as I was rephrasing the question I realized that code block could work if I put it inside a `setInterval()`. Something like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
    const time = moment();
    if(time >= reminderArray[0].notificationTime){
        bot.sendMessage(reminderArray[0].message);
        reminderArray.shift();
    }     

},6000)
```

Comment: "global time variable that is constantly updated" - are you referring to the system function to get the current time (`Date.now()` or `new Date()` in javascript)? If not, please phrase your question better.

Comment: I think you want `currentDateTime >=`, and to check all array elements which are in the past.

Comment: You're right, thank you for your help and sorry for the vagueness of the question and details surrounding the question.

Answer (score 0):

what about `setTimeout` function? You can wrap in setTimeout your function, and your function will be called after N milliseconds, first argument function, second, time in milliseconds, for example:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('I remind you');
}, 1000)
```

For your first case, remind me in x minutes, you can use previous, for the second case: remind me to do 'y' on April 30th at 9:00am", you can use something like that:

```
const reminder = (time) => //argument time in milliseconds which user set
 const now = Date.now();
 setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('I remind you');
    }, now + time - now)
```

For more information about Date.now and setTimeout visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Hope I could help you!